# How to implement App Tracking Transparency in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, apptrackingtransparency

I submitted my app to apple but it got rejected because i haven't added App transparency. SO far, i have imported the dependency into pubspec.yaml and i'm confused if there is more that i need to add to my main.dart in the below code, please help

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:app_tracking_transparency/app_tracking_transparency.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'app.dart';
import 'models/constants.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final TrackingStatus status =
  await AppTrackingTransparency.requestTrackingAuthorization();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(directory.path);
  await Hive.openBox(Constants.bookmarkTag);
  await Hive.openBox(Constants.resentSearchTag);
  await Hive.openBox(Constants.notificationTag);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));

  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [Locale('en'), Locale('ar'), Locale('es')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),

      //Defaut language
      startLocale: Locale('en'),
      useOnlyLangCode: true,
      child: MyApp(),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For iOs you need to specify a key in the Info.plist.

Open file app/ios/Runner/Info.plist
and add the following line:

NSUserTrackingUsageDescription
This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.

As it is specified in the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/app_tracking_transparency